# Clang - Detect when header files are done

Tags: c++, llvm-clang, clang-ast-matchers

I'm new to clang and I'm trying to add a **#include<>** after all the other includes are done.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math>
// I want to add my include here.
```

I apologize if this is a silly question. But I'm not able to find which AST Matcher does this. I am referring to :

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html

Comment: Can you add more details of what you are trying to do? Why? And how? Is this part of your build system, if so which one? etc.

Comment: I don't understand. What stops you from adding an `#include` at the end of other includes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure AST analysis will help much: #include directives are replaced by the preprocessor before the code is parsed into AST. It seems they are not represented in the AST.

A different approach might be Clang's preprocessor hooks, which allow one to register callbacks at various points during preprocessing:

https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html